# C++ advice how to break a while loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm building a battleships game and I need some advices how to deal with this problem.

Okey so the problem is that the game ends when **both** players has shoot down all the ships, this is controlled by a while loop and i want it to break as fast as one player has shot down the opponent.

The problem is at the function `void ShootAtShip(int board1[], int board2[], string names[], int cap)` and the while loop says `while ((board1[i] != 0 || board2[i] != 0))` what I think is the problem is that the while loop has to run all the way from top to bottom before it ends, I want it to break in the middle IF board1 gets all 0's.

```
    bool isGameOver(int board1[], int board2[], int cap)
{
    bool lost1 = true;
    bool lost2 = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < cap && lost1 != false; ++i)
        if (board1[i] != 0)
            lost1 = false;
    if (lost1)
        return true;
    for (int i = 0; i < cap && lost2 != false; ++i)
        if (board2[i] != 0)
            lost2 = false;
    return lost2;
}

void ShootAtShip(int board1[], int board2[], string names[], int cap) {
    const int hit = 0;
    int shot = 0;
    int temp;
    isGameOver(board1, board2, cap);

    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        while ((board1[i] != 0 || board2[i] != 0)) { //detects if any board has all their ships shot down

            cout << names[1] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
            cin >> shot;
            temp = shot;

            while ((shot >= cap) || (shot < 0)) {       //detects if the number is allowed
                cout << "That number is not allowed, " << names[1] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
                cin >> shot;
            }

            if (board1[shot] != 0) {
                board1[shot] = 0;
                cout << "Hit!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You missed." << endl;
            }

            shot = 0;

            cout << names[0] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
            cin >> shot;

            while ((shot >= cap) || (shot < 0)) {       //detects if the number is allowed
                cout << "That number is not allowed, " << names[0] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
                cin >> shot;
            }

            if (board2[shot] != 0) {
                board2[shot] = 0;
                cout << "Hit!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You missed." << endl;
            }

        }


    }



    cout << "Testing is while loop stops";
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to post entire code? It is much harder for us to really help you if we have to go through all this. Always try to simplify the problem as much as possible.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this? Is it broken? Or is it needing optimization?

Comment: changed the code to a smaler one, the problem is that the while loop wont break when ONE of the boards gets all zeros ONLY when both gets all zero.

Comment: So, you want to continue the only loop if `board1[i] != 0` **AND** `board2[i] != 0`?

Comment: Ah. OK I will write my answer on this.

Comment: `i ` never gets modified inside the loop.

Comment: updated to a little more understandable

Comment: `i` doesn't seem to need to be modified inside the loop, since it is already incremented in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 4):

So the reason the loop does not break is because you are using the wrong logic operator in your condition.

`while ((board1[i] != 0 || board2[i] != 0))`
should be
`while (board1[i] && board2[i])`

I believe you're thinking "if board 1 is empty or board 2 is empty, then break", but what you typed out is "if board 1 has anything left, or board 2 has anything left, keep going".

Also, do note that `if (n != 0)` is potentially more efficient (and just the same) as `if (n)`.

Comment: Okey, I want that the loop break when either one has all 0's, so like this then? **while (board1[i] != 0 && board2[i] != 0)**

Comment: Oh, to break if all items in the array are 0? That is different.

Comment: In that case, you might want another function that returns a `bool` such as `bool IsBoardAlive (<...>* board) {<...>};`. The content might be something like `for (int cur = 0; cur < n_items; cur++) if (*(items_list + cur)) return true; return false;`, and your loop condition could be `while (IsBoardAlive(board1) && IsBoardAlive(board2)) {<...>};`. You get the idea?

Comment: Because `i` is counting what number of game it is, so #1: `board1[i]` or `board2[i]` with a `cap` higher than [the number of items in either of those arrays minus 1], you will be dereferencing the wrong memory, most likely resulting in a crash, and #2: it probably won't check what you're wanting to -- it will only evaluate the value at offset `i` from `board1` and `board2`, not all the values in those arrays.